# CKEditor not displayed in some of my website pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my website for adding new pages. In adding page ckeditor works well but in editing pages when I try exactly same code on this page it is not showing up and only a simple textarea is shown!

here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <textarea id="ckeditor" name="full_txt" required><?php echo $pages['fulltxt']; ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have included this also:

```
<script src="plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and a bit of javascript:

```
$(function () {
    //CKEditor
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor');
    CKEDITOR.config.height = 300;
});
```

this is working on a page and not working on another page just in that directory, what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you get some errors in browser console?
Another thing: I'm not an expert with jQuery also. but are you sure this "bit of javascript" is executed? Can you actually put some `console.log()` together with `CKEDITOR.replace` and check if it's printed out?

Comment: This code is working on another page!